# javamail inline image refuses to honor any style

Tags: jakarta-mail

I am using Javamail to send an email with an HTML message that includes an inline image.

Please.  Before anyone writes "asked and answered", see the following:

On the web:  http://america-3.org:8080/ opens a page where you will see a link I labeled "X" in the lower left corner of the banner.  If you click it you will see the page exactly as I'd like it to show up in email. I used child colors just to see what's happening.  But the key point is the image and font size adjust when you reduce browser size. (for now I'm just testing in Firefox).  And it is  100% css>  No tables.

Then see HTML code below.  It attempts the same thing using TABLES, because email clients can't handle 100% css.  If you cut and paste it, it should work without modification.  In this case the spacing is a little screwed up by some unnecessary borders I added to see what's going on, but other wise is close enough to know the approach works.

Now here's the problem.  I send the exact HTML code in a Javamail email -- EXCEPT -- I embed the image in the email, and then retrieve it with src="cid:image".  But then when opened in Outlook,  the image refuses to honor any formatting instructions.  Outlook just displays the image in its native size ... period!

I've tried these, and a 100 other variations, and none has had any effect on the image.  It is always its own size.:

```
<img src="cid:<image>" width="100%" height ="auto">
<img style="width:100%;height:auto;">
```

Actually nothing I do has any effect on the image.  borders don't show, margins are ignored, ditto padding (regardless of whether I provide them with attributes or style.

So before I waste more days beating my head against a wall, can anyone help point me to a solution? I mean it seems impossible that no one has ever done that, but no matter how I search I can't find an example. When I send the email with Javamail  and and open it with Outlook, the image will not budge ... period.

```
<html>
  <head>
   <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body style="background:#444444#; text-align:center;">
    <table style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;
                  text-align:center;
                  width:80%; 
                  border:10px solid black; background:yellow;
                  border-collapse:separate;
                  font-size:250%;">
      <tr >
         <td style="width:20%;
                    padding:10px; margin:10px; 
                    border:10px solid orange; 
                    background:blue;">
           <img src="http://america-3.org:8080/images/TAPP-Great-Seal-Small-2014-12-21.jpg" 
                     style="height:auto; width:90%; height:auto;
                            border:10px solid green;">
         </td>
         <td    style="width:70%;
                       padding:10px; margin:10px; 
                       border:10px solid orange;  
                       background:red;">
           2nd table cell</td>
       </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This sounds like more of an Outlook problem than a JavaMail problem.  JavaMail will send whatever you want it to send, but your problem is in how it's being displayed.  You might try viewing the message in Thunderbird or in the Gmail web user interface to see if it will display as you want it to there.  In general, it's probably a bad idea to assume all mail readers will handle the full set of html display capabilities that browsers will.

Comment: Hi Bill, thank you for the advice. Guess my quest to send the image with the email is hopeless. The fix is to take out image (src="cid:image") and use (src="Http//..."). That worked. So whether it is Javamail or Outlook seems a chicken and egg problem.  But I'd say if Javamail can't add images in a way that Outlook can handle properly,its more a Javamail (i.e. Oracle) problem to fix.  Outlook is one of the biggest clients, and getting an imgage to behave normally within an Old World table/cell is about as primative as it gets.  Thanks again, and  Merry Christmas.

Comment: JavaMail has no control over how Outlook displays the html content that you give it.  If you can figure out the right html content to make Outlook do what you want, JavaMail can send it.  Outlook has complete control over the display of the data, and you have complete control over the content of the data, JavaMail just sends it.